# Why triple nested for loop doesn't work the 2nd time in C?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

Edid: Thanks for the suggestions, but none of them work for the FOR loop error.
Why the triple nested for loop(line 82 - 98) works only the first time(correctly) and then it just spits crazy random numbers? The first time it works so good and then it does everything wrong. Thanks for the help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// 2 players, 5 zara, 3 puti(ako ne si gi haresa), moje da pazite:
//1 qift
// 2 qifta
// ful: 1*2 i 1*3
// 5 ednakvi: general
// 4 ednakvi
// 1*3
// 5 poredni
// shans
// izpulnqvase 8 puti i moje da se zapazva zara (samo pri 1 i 2 hvurlane)
int np, otg[5], otg10[5];

int check_pairs(int *otg10, int time){
        int dicecopy[5];
        memcpy(dicecopy, otg10, sizeof(int) * 5); 
        for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++){
            printf("%d " , dicecopy[k]);
        }
    int pairs = 0, sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            if(dicecopy[i] == dicecopy[j])
                pairs++;
        }
    }

    // points
        if(pairs == 1*2 || pairs == 2*2){
            printf("GGGGGGG");
            for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++){
                sum += dicecopy[k];
            }
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
        return sum;
}

int main(){

    printf("How many players do you want: ");
        scanf("%d" , &np);
    int points[np];
    for(int i = 0; i < np; i++){
        points[i] = 0;
    }

    int dice[8][np][3][5];
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < np; j++){
            for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++){
                for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++){
                    dice[i][j][c][k] = rand() % 6 + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*     for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < np; j++){
            for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++){
                for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++){
                    printf("%d " , dice[i][j][c][k]);
                }
                putchar('\n');
            }
            putchar('\n');
        }
        putchar('\n\n');
    } 
    */
    char anws = 'y';

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < np; j++){
            printf("\nPlayer: %d\nPoints: %d\n" , j + 1 , points[j]);
            for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++){
                for(int l = 0; l < 5; l++){
                    otg10[l] = dice[i][j][k][l];
                    printf("%d " , otg10[l]);
                }
                printf("\n\nDo you like it?\n");
                scanf("%s" , &anws);
                if(anws == 'y' || anws == 'Y'){
                    points[j] = check_pairs(otg10 , k);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code is still not finished I have to do more work on the other check-ups. BTW this will represent the game called Generala, if you have any suggestions I'd like to hear them!

Comment: In `int points[np];`, the variable `np` does not yet have a value. So `points` has an indeterminate size.

Comment: Turn warnings of your compiler on. It would have told you.

Comment: You need to place `int points[np];` _after_ the `scanf`.

Comment: `scanf("%s" , &anws);` ==> `scanf(" %c", &anws);` note the added space too. The format `%s` is for a string, and the added space is to filter leading whitespace that may be left in the input.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: `np` is global so it gets initialized with zero.  So the size of `points` isn't indeterminate but simply zero.  But of course that is bad.

Comment: regarding: `srand(time(NULL));`  to eliminate the warning message (when you have enabled the warnings, as you always should when compiling)  suggest using: `srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );`  Note horizontal spacing for human readability

Comment: regarding: `int check_pairs(int *otg10, int time){`  1)  the parameter `time` is not used, so should be removed  2) the parameter `time` has the same name as exposed via the statement: `#include <time.h>`  It is very poor programming practice to use variable names that are the same as the C library names

Comment: My time's up, but one finding: on the second run of the loop `dice` has *another* address as on the first run. Try to dig deeper.

Comment: post a [mcve] that includes all inputs, what you expected for outputs and the actual outputs.  Then add an explanation of what you are expecting the posted code to perform

Comment: since you want to represent the game of: `Generala`, please post the rules for that game